# Issue while invoking a form from another using System.Window.Forms.Invoke(delegate)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have two forms and 1 singleton class. I am initalizing the singleton class in btn_A_Click of formA.

```
public partial class frmA : Form
{
    public frmA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmB frmB;
    }

    private void btn_A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SessionMgmt.GetInstance().StartFormB(); 
    }
}
```

This is my singleton class and here I am trying to use Forms.Invoke() method.

```
public class SessionMgmt
{
    static SessionMgmt _sessinMgr;
    frmB frB;

    private SessionMgmt()
    {
        frB = new frmB();
    }

    public static SessionMgmt GetInstance()
    {
        if (_sessinMgr != null)
            return _sessinMgr;
        else
        {
            _sessinMgr = new SessionMgmt();
            return _sessinMgr;
        }
    }

    public bool StartFormB()
    {
        frB.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayFrmB));
        return true;
    }

    private void DisplayFrmB(Object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        frB.Visible = true;
        frB.Refresh();
    }
```

}

This is my formB.

```
public partial class frmB : Form
{
}
```

But from the `frB.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayFrmB));` method it throws the following exception:

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

I can't figure out the issue, please help or advice me if I miss anything.

**EDIT**

The following structure is the way my current project is displaying the next form. It was done by VB.NET and I need to use similar kind of thing in the new project which uses C#. I saw the Invoke function which points to an event and then to a function. In that function it just makes the Form.Visible=true and Form.Refresh. But for understanding I just tried a POc and followed the same steps ,but it is not yet solved.

Comment: Can you post the bare minimum vb.net code you are trying to replicate?

Answer (score 2):

What is reason to call invoke? Isn't this doing the job for you?

```
public bool StartFormB()
{
    frB.Visible = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @VeeKayBee: why do you need to use `Invoke`?

Comment: I would tend to agree. Why do you need to `Invoke`? The only purpose of that function on a form is to ensure that you are running code on the thread that created the form (because windows have thread affinity and .NET will throw an exception if you don't). But if you haven't created the form yet, you can't be running on the wrong thread unless you call `StartFormB` from a background thread. And if it's only called from a button click handler, you are running on the same thread as form A.

Comment: And a little more clarification, you can't technically be on the wrong thread at all if the form hasn't been created yet. But if you want to have only one thread with an event loop then you would need to make sure you are on form A's thread. If you need to do that, then `Invoke` on form A.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is a wrapper around the Windows API, and that exception means the underlying window hasn't been created yet. I think it gets created when you set `Visible` to `true` for the first time, and there are a few other situations that do it.

See this link for a possible solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mapo/archive/2011/04/27/forcing-handle-creation-in-a-net-windows-forms-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible reasons for that exception:

- The form isn't created when the invoke is called
- It's possible that you're creating your controls on the wrong thread

you should always check the `InvokeRequired` Property before Invoking, and of course check for null before that

```
public bool StartFormB()
{
    if (frB == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("frB");
    }

   if (frB.InvokeRequired)
   {

        frB.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayFrmB));
   }
   else
   {    
      if (frB.IsDisposed)
      {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("Control is already disposed.");
      }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: It isn't actually harmful to call `Invoke` if `InvokeRequired` is `false`.

Comment: yes it is, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

Comment: That page says `InvokeRequired` can return `false` if the call would occur on the same thread or if the handle hasn't been created yet. It is only harmful in situations where `IsHandleCreated` would return `false`. Otherwise, it just makes the call on the same thread. `Invoke` is almost certainly a wrapper for `SendMessage`. Given the code here, the handle will not have been created. A call to `InvokeRequired` will return `false` and the form will not be displayed as desired.

Comment: @LiranElisha what is DisplayFrmB  ?

Answer (score 0):

Control handle IS NOT created if the control's Visible property is false. When you call Invoke you set your controls visible state to true in delegate, but handle is not created yet, so you can not call Invoke. So - you must call frB.CreateHandle(); after: frB = new frmB(); to force creation of control handle

```
    private SessionMgmt()
    {
        frB = new frmB();
        var h = frB.Handle;
    }
```

Comment: I got it. Control handle IS NOT created if the control's Visible property is false. When you call Invoke you set your controls visible state to true in delegate, but handle is not created yet, so you can not call Invoke. So - you must call frB.CreateHandle(); after: frB = new frmB(); to force creation of control handle

Comment: @AndriyVandych: `CreateHandle()` is not public method. But you can invoke it by querying the `Handle` proprty - `var h = frB.Handle;`

Comment: @YK1: you're right, it's my fault. Call to Handle property is good way.